# How to drop request json properties in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I am fairly new to express-js, so this question might seem silly, but been looking around and I can't find a elegant answer.

For a given  route handling a post or put method, I want to be able to drop all of the properties not specified. For example if there is a post request to create an obj as:

```
{  
title: "some title",
user: "some user",
body: "post body",
_id: "1332433242343",
}
```

I want to be able to have a middleware which only takes the properties that I need, such as:

```
(req, res, next) => {
   const { title, user, body } = req.body;
   clean_request = { title: title, user: user, body: body, };
}
```

The reason being that not malicious agent, could manipulate the internal database data, as the _id property is user by the database, and it can be set by the requester.

I am using express-validate to validate an sanitize my properties, but so far I have not found a way to be able to drop properties entirely and keep only the ones I need.

Thanks again, for any advice. ^^

Comment: You can use [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator). `class-transformer` drops all additional properties with `excludeExtraneousValues`

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could make your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

at then end of the day I ended up writting my own middle ware for droppping unwanter properties in a the req body:

```
allowed_properties = {
    username: true,
    lastname: true,
    firstname: true,
    condition: true,
    image: true,
    password: true,
    email: true,
 }

const cleanProperties = (req, res, next) => {
        /* clean the json of any unwanted properties */
        const clean_json = {}
        Object.keys(req.body).forEach(
                property => // for property
                allowedProperties[property] &&  // if is make as acceptable
                (clean_json[property] = req.body[property]) // pass to new obj
        );
        req.body = clean_json;
        next();
}
```